# Refreshing a view after context.pop() with go_router and bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I have 2 different views with two different blocs.
One page displays data that is edited on the second page.
When I upload values from my bloc on the second page and execute a context.pop to return to the first page, the first page doesn’t reaload and since they’re separate bloc, it’s not noticing any change

I am using go_router (i can’t use navigator for navigation)
I tried to make an async call to execute after it comes back but i couldn’t

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by adding unique keys to my pages in go router!

see more here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100969#issuecomment-1289944809